# Antireflection coating: does reflection that destructively interferes lead to more transmitted light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, solar-cells

I was watching some media on how solar cells work, and the description of the antireflective coating confused me.

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/LveK9R3E3bw?t=634) and [this Physics Asylum video](https://youtu.be/8RjGHmlOu58?t=159), the antireflection coating is optimized to cause destructive interference between reflections from the top and bottom interfaces of this layer. This light is now not being reflected, we get more transmission of light into the PV that can be converted into energy.

Is this really how it works? If two reflected photons' phases cancel out due to destructive interference, why would that lost intensity then be added to the portion of light that transmitted through?

Comment: Do you understand how a quarter-wave plate works?

Comment: Don't get too stuck on "light is photons" .  Try to view this as a couple standing waves and you'll see what's going on

Answer (score 2):

In wave interference, the energy has to go **somewhere**. So, if interference cancels the radiation in a particular direction it must enhance it in another.

Answer (score 1):

Its best to think of this in terms of transmission and intensity. Suppose that light traveling through air encounters a material with index of refraction $n_m$ The transmission of of light through the material can be described as

$$I_0 = I_{R} + I_{T}$$
$$I_{T} = I_0 - I_{R}$$
where $I_{R}$ and $I_{T}$ are the reflected and transmitted intensities.

Suppose now, a different material of given thickness and different index of refraction is deposited on top of the original material (anti-reflection coating AR), then the transmission of light through this material can be described as:

$$ I_0 = I_{AR(reflected)} + I_{AR(transmitted)}$$ and then that light is reflected from and transmitted through the material/AR boundary $$I_{AR(transmitted)} = I^{'}_{AR(reflected)} + I^{'}_T
$$
Finally

$$I_0 = I_{AR(reflected)} + I^{'}_{AR(reflected)} + I^{'}_T$$

Clearly if the two reflected components could cancel each other out$$I_{AR(reflected)} + I^{'}_{AR(reflected)} = 0$$ then 100% transmission would be possible $$I^{'}_T = I_0$$

This is what AR coating design takes advantage of and how the destructive interference that cancels these reflected waves increases transmission.